# mysqli_connect() isn't selecting database? and can't insert data

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this code

```
<?php 
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db_name="mydb";
    $db_connect=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username,$db_password, $db_name);
    //check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_error()){ 
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" .mysqli_connect_error();
    } else{
        echo "Connection successful" ; 
    }
?>
```

When i run the code it shows "Connection successful" but when i input data into a table that is in the database it gives me an error "No database selected"

I tried the code below and it seems to work, other than the fact that the Auto increment value (ID) isn't passed into the database so it gives me an error which means that "the data passed in row 1 doesn't match the datatype. "(Shouldn't it not be required to be entered, and with each insert query gets updated automatically?) I am passing values to the table using and insert statement and not in array form, maybe?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    $connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die($connect_error);
    mysql_select_db('mydb') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

I was asked to provide the code i'm using for inserting data into the table.

```
   <?php   
    require_once ('dbconnect.php');

    $title= "my title";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username =    $_POST['username'];
    $password =    $_POST['password'];
    $class =       $_POST['class'];
    $type =        $_POST['type'];
    $description = $_POST ['description'];
    $date = date(d-m-y);

    $sql= "INSERT into mytable values ('username, password, class, type, description')" ;
    $qry= mysql_query($sql) ;  

    if (!$qry) {
      echo "Something went wrong: " . mysql_error();}

      else echo "Finished successfully";
}


    ?>
```

Comment: `when i input data into a table` please share that code also.

Comment: @Rishi Done. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`.

use below code to fire mysql query

```
mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql);
```

replace this line

```
$qry= mysql_query($sql) ;
```

to

```
$qry= mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql);
```

Comment: To connect to the database i'm using mysqli and to insert into the table i'm using mysql _query() if that's what you mean. Also i'm using PHP 5.6, if that should be a concern. I tried your suggestion and it gave the same error, no database selected.

Comment: `mysql_query` isn't used with mysqli. Use `mysqli_query` instead.

Comment: @cHao I used mysqli_query($qry) and it got an error saying that the function requires at least two inputs to be used, i tried ($qry, $qry) and it gave some error saying that the first input should be a string... what's this mess? haha when I use the dbconnect code using mysql_connect() and input using mysql_query, everything works. But mysqli is the future since mysql_qury has been removed from PHP 7 :\  could the problem be that i'm using PHP 5.6?

Comment: @Mar1ak: No, the problem is that you're not reading the PHP documentation. :P  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @cHao I did go through it quickly and thought it was unclear :p. I had two errors, one was mixing mysqli in the dbconnect.php while using mysql_query in the other page. And then I was confused about the second parameter to use with mysqli_query other than the insert statement, used the connection variable and it now works. Thanks for your effort man you're great. =)

Answer (score 0):

Latest Version of php uses mysqli object (mysql improved) insted of methods for accessing mysql database.

```
    <?php 

    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db_name="mydb";

    $db_connect=new mysqli($db_host, $db_username,$db_password, $db_name);


    //check connection
    if ($db_connect -> connect_error)
    { 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:".$db_connect->connect_error;
    }
    else{
    echo "Connection successful" ; }

    ?>
```

Comment: The procedural interface is still a perfectly valid way to use mysqli.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.6. Should that be a concern?
I used your code, and same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had two mistakes, one was mixing mysqli in the dbconnect.php while using mysql_query in the other page. And then I was confused about the second parameter to use with mysqli_query other than the insert statement, used the connection variable and it now works.

Comment: Oh!! I said the same.

Comment: Yes I've marked your answer as best answer, thank you.